# Java executes "if" block when condition is demonstrably false

Tags: java

[image: Screen shot of my problem.]

This pretty much says it all. `paneNum` is 0. Test for `paneNum < 0` is apparently `true` since the instruction pointer is inside the if-block, and the function returns `false`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you force the cast of paneNum into Integer?

Comment: What does that `[^@ (NUL)]` mean?

Comment: I suspect a code/compilation unit de-sync.

Comment: Robert: Check your ASCII table - ^@ (Ctrl+@) is how one would type null if one could type null. Ctrl+I is tab (ASCII 9), Ctrl+H is backspace (ASCII 8), so by extension, Ctrl+@ would be NUL (ASCII 0). :-)

Comment: Dave: I suspect a compiler bug. Clean and rebuild doesn't help. Exit Eclipse and re-launch doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Was the conditional changed recently from something like `paneNum <= 0`?  My guess is that there is a synchronization issue between the code being executed and the code you are debugging.

Try cleaning the project and rebuilding it.  I suspect it will work fine.

Comment: This code hasn't changed recently. While it's been compiled a few times, this is the first time I've traced into it since it wasn't working. I tried a clean and rebuild but no luck. Ended up with 

if ( paneNum >= 0)
  {
  }
else
  {
  return false;
  }

That works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with the most updated version of the file that you're debugging.  You could think that you are in the statement and not be actually there.  Also run in display mode while you're at that breakpoint something like:

```
System.out.println(paneNum);
System.out.println(paneNum < 0);
```

Comment: Agree with your answer except for the last part. `paneNum` is a primitive, so `paneNum == null` doesn't make sense.  The default value for a java int is 0.

Comment: Ah yes I looked at the NUL and thought it was an Integer

Comment: I didn't try printing paneNum < 0, but when I print paneNum, it says 0 inside the "paneNum < 0" block.